# HTML: How to increase width of table columns when the table is inside a div with fixed width

Tags: html, css

The following piece of HTML code creates a table inside a div of fixed width. It seems that the "th,td" width is inherited from the parent div (but the W3 documentation says that it is not a inherited property!).

**How do I increase the width of table columns (say 500px)?**

You can see that changing the width value in "th, td" selector does not have any impact on width.

Please note:
- I do not want to change the width of div
- I do not want to set a fixed width to my table
- I have tried "table-layout: fixed;" inside table selector. It did not make the "td,th" width property work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            table, td, th {
                border:1px solid black;
            }
            th, td {
                /* Changing width doesn't make any difference */
                width:500px;
            }
            .myclass {
                width:200px;
                overflow:auto
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="myclass">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Savings</th>
                    <th>Expenditure</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Griffin</td>
                    <td>$100</td>
                    <td>$50</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your code,total width of the container is 200px and you are setting the td width to 500px.
How is that possible.

Comment: @Sharath: overflow:auto in .myclass lets me scroll through the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, made it work!

"table-layout:fixed; width:100%" did the trick...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        table, td, th {
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        th, td {
            /* Changing width doesn't make any difference */
            width:500px;
        }
        .myclass {
            width:200px;
            overflow:auto
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="myclass">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Savings</th>
                <th>Expenditure</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>Griffin</td>
                <td>$100</td>
                <td>$50</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use percentages?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qCYDq/

also you are limiting yourself with 200px in width, if the text inside the table (word width) is larger than your 200px it will force its width and then cause your scroller to appear as the table will stretch to fit the words.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 9px;
}
td,th { 
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 25%;
}
.myclass
{
    width:200px;
    overflow:auto
}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
<div class="myclass">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>Firstname</th>
           <th>Lastname</th>
           <th>Savings</th>
           <th>Expenditure</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Peter</td>
           <td>Griffin</td>
           <td>$100</td>
           <td>$50</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use inline-css unnecessarily

Comment: cannot assign td or th widths via the css??
You can!

Comment: @SimonStaton: Thanks for your response but percentages do not have any effect either! Please note that I want all columns to have same width. I should be able to set the width in px.

Comment: @SimonStaton: Do I really need to change the font size to make it work? I hope not.

Comment: If you make the font-size bigger (as the div is so small) it will make the table bigger than the div and cause it to scroll, unless this is what you want, you cannot make letters go on new lines to fit. Making the width "25%" will make the columns even. Please could you explain what you mean by not having any effect? Maybe provide a jsfiddle of what you are doing.

Comment: Sure. Please check here - http://jsfiddle.net/nishant80/sFK89/ You can modify the td,th width percent value but it wont change the width of columns. Please note that I have removed the font-size property as I don't need to set it. Scrolling is fine with me and that is why I have used the overflow property. Actually, this is just a sample. My real table can have >50 columns.

Comment: Why is the th and td width 120%? in my example it is 25%, it is impossible to make the columns bigger by 20% than the table itself.

Comment: You can change the width and see it has no effect on the actual width of table. Please see my previous comment for details (you posted while I was editing it!)

Comment: It is not working because table width is "200px" inherited from the container which sets this width, then making the columns 25% of this "50px" but your text at the font-size it is on for example "Firstname" is "70px" wide and so is expanding the table, how are you expecting the text to react when the width is to small? the only solution is to make the font-size smaller so it fits inside your "50px" width

Comment: @SimonStaton: Thanks for trying out solutions. I got the fix, please see my answer.